# How can I search a SQL database with multiple "%" wildcards?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to write a SQL query in SQL Server 2008 R2 that will allow a user to search a database table by a number of parameters. The way this should work is, my user enters his criteria and the query looks for all close matches, while ignoring those criteria for which the user did not enter a value.

I've written my query using `LIKE` and parameters, like so:

```
select item 
from [item] 
where a like @a and b like @b and c like @c ...
```

where '`a`', '`b`', and '`c`' are table columns, and my `@` parameters all default to '`%`' wildcards. This goes on for about twenty different columns, and that leads to my problem: if this query is entered as is, no input, just wildcards, it returns no results. Yet this table contains over 30,000 rows, so an all-wildcard query should return the whole table. Obviously I'm going about this the wrong way, but I don't know how to correct it.

I can't use '`contains`' or '`freetext`', as those look for whole words, and I need to match user input no matter where it occurs in the actual column value. I've tried breaking my query up into individual steps using 'intersect', but that doesn't change anything. Does anyone know a better way to do this?

Comment: Remember null is not like '%'

Comment: @jarlh Alex is right, null isn't going to work. I need to return all items in my table where the columns associated with criteria the user entered contain that criteria anywhere within their actual value, and then disregard column values associated with criteria the user didn't enter. So if the user entered 'foo' for @a and left @b and @c alone, the query would be "where a like '%foo%' and b like '%' and c like '%'".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the guidance, all. It turns out that the table I'm querying can easily contain null values in the columns I'm searching against, so I expanded my query to say "where (a like @a or a is null) and ... " and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

To allow for null inputs, this is a good pattern:

```
select * from my table where ColA LIKE isnull(@a, ColA) AND ColB like isnull(@b, ColB)
```

This avoids having to construct and execute a dynamic SQL statement (and creating possible SQL injection issues.)

Comment: Eh, it went from being an improvement to its own thing, I removed the reference to Kid Code's answer.

Answer (score 0):

> my @ parameters all default to '%' wildcards

Don't do this. Default them to null. The way to disregard empty parameters is with a short circuit:

```
(@a IS NULL OR @a LIKE a)
```

Depending on how you want to handle missing data in the column, you might want a third term, because null will not match LIKE statements:

```
(@a IS NULL OR a IS NULL OR @a LIKE a)
```

> How can I search a SQL database with multiple "%" wildcards?

*Slowly*. SQL is suboptimal for doing text comparisons. The best approach is to perform this search somewhere else, or at least structure your data to facilitate these kinds of queries. If you know you'll be performing a lot of these queries, consider redesigning your schema in the shape of a [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree). At an absolute bare minimum, do something so that every LIKE match is suffix-only, meaning LIKE 'xxx%' and never LIKE '%xxx' or LIKE 'x%x'. The latter two preclude the use of indexes. And put an index on every column you need to search.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I'd do this in the application layer (assuming you have one), and build the query around the parameters the user supplies, eliminating the ones they don't.

For example, the following bit of code builds the query in SQL, where only the parameters the user has supplied (not `null`) are included in the where clause.

**NOTE:** This is *very* crude, as it doesn't take into account `AND`'s if the first parameter if null, and it doesn't remove the `WHERE` clause if no parameters are supplied. If you let me know what language your application layer is built in, I'll provide a better example. **(This is purely pseudo-code!)**

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(100) = '''%SomeValue%''', @b VARCHAR(100)= '''%AnotherValue%''', @c VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE'

IF @a IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @SQL += ' ColA LIKE ' + @a
END

IF @b IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @SQL += ' AND ColA LIKE ' + @b
END

IF @c IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @SQL += ' AND ColC LIKE ' + @c
END

PRINT @SQL

--EXEC(@SQL)
```

**Output:**

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ColA = '%SomeValue%' AND ColB = '%AnotherValue%'
```

Comment: You want LIKE, not = for those wildcard searches.

Comment: Also, you would run into problems if `@a` was `NULL`. Your concatenated `WHERE` clause would be `WHERE AND ColB = '%value%'...` etc...

Comment: Dynamic SQL can only reuse query plans when the generated text is exactly the same. This is going to perform poorly, even if you fix the correctness issues.

Comment: @gmiley, I believe I mentioned that in the 'Note' section! :)